# Automapper mapping sub items

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to use Automapper to map from a frontend object hierarchy to a backend object hierarchy. This necessitates creating a subcomponent on the fly from several sources in the source object. I've done this in other places with no trouble. But in the case, the newly created object requires its own properties to also be mapped.

I've added a generic version of what I am talking about below.

```
config.CreateMap<BusinessObject, WebObject>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Component, opts => opts.ResolveUsing(b =>
    {
        return new ComponentBusinessObject()
        {
            Date = b.Property1.Date,
            Definition = b.Property2.Definition  // This needs converting from (DefinitionWebObject to DefinitionBusinessObject)
        };
    }));
```

Does anyone know a way of re-invoking the mapper at the lower level? ('Definition' in the example above.)

Comment: Have you tried using "Definition = Mapper.Map(b.Property2.Definition)" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off of GTG's comment:

If you map `DefinitionWebObject` and `DefinitionBusinessObject` together prior to your `BusinessObject` and `WebObject` mapping, you should be able to call Mapper.Map inside your parent map.

```cs
config.CreateMap<DefinitionWebObject, DefinitionBusinessObject>();  // Create sub-mapping first.

config.CreateMap<BusinessObject, WebObject>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Component, opts => opts.ResolveUsing(b =>
    {
        return new ComponentBusinessObject()
        {
            Date = b.Property1.Date,
            Definition = Mapper.Map<DefinitionBusinessObject>(b.Property2.Definition)
        };
    }));
```